# the index value is shown on terminal but is undefined while trying to utilize in code

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-fns

I'm trying to work with some data that has close bindings to dates. As shown in the snippet down below I'm trying to find the index of the closest day to today. I'm using `date-fns` utility library for this job. While I'm trying to log the `closestIndex` from it works fine and got an output in the terminal but while I'm trying to utilize the value of `closestIndex` I got an error that says `closestIndex` is `undefined`.
Any Ideas would be very appreciated.

```js
import * as dateFns from 'date-fns';

const today = new Date().getTime();
const dates = [
  2022-04-10T14:07:12.276Z,
  2022-04-10T14:07:06.967Z,
  2022-04-10T14:07:04.663Z,
  2022-04-10T14:07:03.040Z,
  2022-04-10T14:07:01.420Z,
  2022-04-10T14:06:59.869Z,
  2022-04-10T14:06:53.223Z
]

const closestIndex = dateFns.closestTo(today, dates);

console.log(closestIndex); // => 0

console.log(dates[closestIndex]); // => undefined could not be used as index value
```

Comment: [*closestTo*](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/closestTo) returns the closest element from the array, not its index. Assuming *dates* is an array of *Dates* and it's currently after 10 April, it will return the Date at index 0, not the index "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use real Date objects inside your array (rather than ISO-8601 values which are not even quoted) and use [closestIndexTo](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/closestIndexTo) instead of [closestTo](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/closestTo) (which will return the Date value itself rather than its **index** in the array)

```js
const today = new Date().getTime();
const dates = [
  new Date('2022-04-10T14:07:12.276Z'),
  new Date('2022-04-10T14:07:06.967Z'),
  new Date('2022-04-10T14:07:04.663Z'),
  new Date('2022-04-10T14:07:03.040Z'),
  new Date('2022-04-10T14:07:01.420Z'),
  new Date('2022-04-10T14:06:59.869Z'),
  new Date('2022-04-10T14:06:53.223Z')
]

const closestIndex = dateFns.closestIndexTo(today, dates);

console.log(closestIndex); // => 0

console.log(dates[closestIndex]); // => "2022-04-10T14:07:12.276Z"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.js"></script>
```

Comment: Likely it is an array of Dates, the timestamps are just what shows in the console.

Comment: As `RobG` pointed out - you must use `closestIndexTo` to get the index - and `closestTo` to get the Date itself.

Comment: I have changed all the dates to timeStamps, and trying to get the indexOfThe closest date based on the array that I have, while I'm copying one of the items in the array for example 4th I'm getting a valid index based on 4th value that I want to find the closest Index. but I can only read it in the terminal via log function, I can't utilize the value of that in the program

Comment: And as mentioned in the documentation and GitHub source code. we can have both `Number | Date` passed as the first argument and `Number[] | Date[]` passed as the second argument to both of the `closestTo` and `closestIndexTo` functions

Comment: @EmadBaqeri If you run the code snippet you will see how it has both the index and the date values in the console - none of them is undefined.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks for your response, sorry I have not mentioned that I'm trying the same code in javascript and it's working but while I'm pasting code to my main project I get typescript compiler error.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, the actual problem was using ts-node. while I'm trying to test the program with the ts-node I'm getting the same error. when I moved the test code to the project everything works fine. do you have any idea?

Comment: No idea. TypeScript is not my thing.